# Hadoop: How to start secondary namenode on other node?

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to construct hadoop cluster which consists of 1 namenode, 1 secondary namenode, and 3 datanodes in ec2.

So I wrote the address of secondary namenode to the masters file and executed start-dfs.sh .

> :~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ cat masters
>
> ec2-54-187-222-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

But, the secondary namenode didn't start at the address which was written in the masters file. It just started at the node where the stat-dfs.sh script was executed.

> :~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ start-dfs.sh
>
> ...
>
> Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
>
> 0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-26-190.out

I don't figure why secondary namenode started at [0.0.0.0]. It should start at ec2-54-187-222-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Are there anyone who know this reason?

---

Oh I solved this problem. I added

```
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
<value>ec2-54-187-222-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:50090</value>
</property>
```

to hdfs-site.xml file and it works! The masters file is useless.

Comment: This config only defines the http server address. It doesn't ssh to that address and run any processes. Only the slaves file does this https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.6/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

Answer (score -1):

It is okay, as long as the node roles are configured correctly in hadoop configuration. You can use `dfsadmin` to check the IP address of the secondary namenode. If it is `172.31.26.190` then it means fine. The secondary namenode serves at `0.0.0.0` means it accepts any incoming connections from localhost or from any nodes within the network.